# Moment Setup Timezone not working still getting local date time

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

I'm trying to setup a default timezone for moment js

I already imported moment-timezone and use this code

```
var moment = require('moment-timezone');
moment.tz.setDefault('Asia/Taipei');
console.log(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

but when I change my local date in my laptop to April 22, 2022.

Which is April 21,2022 in taipei right now, the console log give me this

```
2022-04-22
```

can you help me set up moment timezone not by my local time but depending on the timezone declared

sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 0):

The momentjs is working as it should. **MomentJs basically gets the current time from computer and then formats it using the timezone you want**. For example If you set your timezone to another country say India then the time in the console will be 2:30 extra. I hope you got it.

If you want time independent of User's Device then you should use Time Apis like https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/Asia/Taipei and make ajax calls to update your time. Like i integrated on the [link](https://nkps6.com/time.html)

Hope it helps.